# Error when I try to import rasterstats

Tags: python, raster, rasterstats

I am getting the following error when importing rasterstats package.

I searched the internet and found no solution. Does anyone know what this is about?

The only command I gave was `import rasterstats`

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 import rasterstats
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterstats/**init**.py in
>
> 2 from .main import gen_zonal_stats, raster_stats, zonal_stats
> 3 from .point import gen_point_query, point_query
> ----> 4 from rasterstats import cli
> 5 from rasterstats._version import **version**
> 6
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterstats/cli.py in 
> 26 @click.option('--stats', type=str, default=None)
> 27 @click.option('--sequence/--no-sequence', type=bool, default=False)
> ---> 28 @cligj.use_rs_opt
> 29 def zonalstats(features, raster, all_touched, band, categorical,
> 30                indent, info, nodata, prefix, stats, sequence, use_rs):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py in
> decorator(f)
> 171             option_attrs['help'] = inspect.cleandoc(option_attrs['help'])
> 172         OptionClass = option_attrs.pop('cls', Option)
> --> 173         _param_memo(f, OptionClass(param_decls, **option_attrs))
> 174         return f
> 175     return decorator
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py in **init**(self,
> param_decls, show_default, prompt, confirmation_prompt, hide_input,
> is_flag, flag_value, multiple, count, allow_from_autoenv, type, help,
> hidden, show_choices, show_envvar, **attrs)    1599
> raise TypeError('Cannot prompt for flags that are not bools.')    1600
> if not self.is_bool_flag and self.secondary_opts:
> -> 1601                 raise TypeError('Got secondary option for non boolean flag.')    1602             if self.is_bool_flag and
> self.hide_input \    1603                and self.prompt is not None:
>
> TypeError: Got secondary option for non boolean flag.

Comment: Try adding information on your setup and what you have done to install rasterstats.  This question might also be better answered in the stackoverflow.com site, tagged #python and #conda

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

It is **incompatibility** with other modules and packages that I use in Data Science.

When this error happens, I recommend that you create a **new environment** and install the package to avoid incompatibilities.